# Postfix: allow inbound relaying from only authenticated MTAs

Tags: authentication, postfix-mta

I want to authenticate our customers' MTAs (Exchange for the most part, pointing to us as its smart host) to our relay server (Postfix 2.11.3, CentOS 6.6) and accept mail from only those authenticated MTAs.

I've looked into SASL, but as far as I can tell, its use case is for authenticating inbound MUAs or outbound MTAs.

How does one authenticate inbound MTAs using Postfix?

Thanks,
Nathan

EDIT:

From my main.cf:

```
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
```

Other useful info: 
postconf -a 
cyrus 
dovecot

vim /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf 
auth_mechanisms = plain login

master.cf is virginal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SASL is the way to go.  Postfix doesn't particularly care of it's an MUA or MTA connecting to it.  If you use `smtpd_sasl_auth_enable` (along with `smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated` and a proper SASL configuration), only authenticated connections will be able to use your server as a smarthost relay.  Exchange supports this sort of thing, and it should be what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, Doug. I'll have another try at it and post results.

Comment: I've pointed an Exchange server to this server as a smart host, and provided the credentials in /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd to the Exchange smart host authentication configuration.

/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd looks like: "hostname.domain.com user:pass" where 'hostname.domain.com' matches the FQDN that appears in /var/log/maillog when this Exchange server tries to connect. When it tries to connect, /var/log/maillog shows: "SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6"

Comment: I think this is the root of my confusion: http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html says that /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd is for destination gateways. I'm looking for a way to authenticate inbound MTAs. Where are those credentials stored?

Comment: I use Dovecot, so I use the Dovecot SASL configuration.  Postfix supports either client or server SASL, you'll want to read through the section entitled "Configuring SASL authentication in the Postfix SMTP server."  It might take a bit of work, but that'll do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you could get it working with Dovecot - I couldn't! Fortunately, I wasn't married to Dovecot. I found this: http://initrd.org/wiki/SMTP_Relay which I followed and succeeded. Just having cert issues, but I'll take that up separately. Thanks again, Doug